# Game of Life Algorithm Issue

Tags: c#

I am writing up a Game of Life program in C#. I am using a 2D array of structs. It seems when I display the Random method that the algorithm of the neighbours or something is wrong. When it goes through generations random  cells are coming "alive" when they are not supposed to. Any help?

```
public struct cellDetail
{
    public int curGenStatus;
    public int nextGenStatus;
    public int age;

}
public class Class1
{

    static cellDetail[,] Generations(cellDetail[,] cells)
    {

        int neighbours = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 60; j++)
                cells[i, j].nextGenStatus = 0;

        for (int row = 0; row < 39; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < 59; col++)
            {
                neighbours = 0;

                if (row > 0 && col > 0)
                {
                    if (cells[row - 1, col - 1].curGenStatus > 0)
                        neighbours++;
                    if (cells[row - 1, col].curGenStatus > 0)
                        neighbours++;
                    if (cells[row - 1, col + 1].curGenStatus > 0)
                        neighbours++;

                    if (cells[row, col - 1].curGenStatus > 0)
                        neighbours++;
                    if (cells[row, col + 1].curGenStatus > 0)
                        neighbours++;

                    if (cells[row + 1, col - 1].curGenStatus > 0)
                        neighbours++;
                }

                if (cells[row + 1, col].curGenStatus > 0)
                    neighbours++;
                if (cells[row + 1, col + 1].curGenStatus > 0)
                    neighbours++;

                if (neighbours < 2)
                    cells[row, col].nextGenStatus = 0;
                if (neighbours > 3)
                    cells[row, col].nextGenStatus = 0;
                if ((neighbours == 2 || neighbours == 3) && cells[row, col].curGenStatus > 0)
                    cells[row, col].nextGenStatus = 1;
                if (neighbours == 3 && cells[row, col].curGenStatus == 0)
                    cells[row, col].nextGenStatus = 1;
            }

        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 60; j++)
                cells[i, j].curGenStatus = cells[i, j].nextGenStatus;

        return cells;
    }

    static void PrintCells(cellDetail[,] cells)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < 40; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 60; col++)
            {
                if (cells[row, col].curGenStatus != 0)
                {
                    cells[row, col].curGenStatus = (char)30;
                    Console.Write((char)cells[row, col].curGenStatus);
                }
                else
                    Console.Write(" ");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Random(int numOfGenerations)
    {
        cellDetail[,] cells = new cellDetail[40,60];
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int row = 0; row < 40; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < 60; col++)
                cells[row, col].curGenStatus = rand.Next(0, 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfGenerations; i++)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor.Green);
            Generations(cells);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
            PrintCells(cells);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Should this have a homework tag?

Comment: I didn't look closely enough to see if it's your underlying issue, but you shouldn't be creating lots of `Random` objects in a short space of time.  They're seeded with the current time by default.  The short answer is just create a `Random` once and store it around so you can call `.Next`on it repeatedly.

Comment: Aye there should be homework tag. I tagged it.

Comment: For the case that `neighbors == 2` and `curGenStatus == 0`, you don't set the `nextGenStatus`.  Which I guess is ok after the first generation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The random object should be created only once and used by all objects of the class.By declaring it as a static member of the class this can be achieved.A better option would be to create a singleton helper class for random object.

Comment: Lets use the proper terminology so as not to confuse people.  `Static` has a specific meaning in C#.  I believe what you were intending is `single instance`.

Comment: From the description of the problem I don't think this is the only issue, and probably not the one the OP is asking about, but still a real problem that he does have.

Comment: @Boo In this case the method using it is static, so it should be a static field.

Comment: @RichardHein: Ah.  It is quite confusing the way it is phrased in the answer.